# Bootstrap img-responsive class doesn't work in Firefox?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Check out the demo here: http://s.codepen.io/resting/debug/WbxBpL?
It looks fine in Chrome and Safari, but the `img-responsive` class doesn't seem to work in Firefox.

Pen: http://codepen.io/resting/pen/WbxBpL

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10690

Adding the following worked.

```
table .img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
}
```